# What're the differences between 12.04.3 LTS desktop and 12.04.3?

Tags: lts

I want to know what are the differences between 12.04.3 lts desktop and 12.04.3. lts

Comment: You mean the difference between `LTS` and non LTS *(All  of `12.04` is LTS to a degree )*, or difference between Ubuntu Desktop, and some other version?

Comment: What exactly are you comparing here?  "Ubuntu" is Ubuntu, whether it's the Desktop images or the Server images.

Comment: 12.04.3 **is** an LTS version. Till now updates and upgrades totalled to 12.04.2. In about a month or so, the next iteration would be out. There is no version of 12.04 which is non-LTS

Answer (score 2):

There are no differences between the two.

"12.04" simply means that the initial release was in April 2012. The "LTS" means that this version (12.04) is supported for 5 years rather than 9 months. The ".3" means that it's the third updated install image for Ubuntu 12.04LTS, which includes all upgrades since the initial release of Ubuntu 12.04LTS in addition to a new kernel with support for new hardware.